# Extracting Vedio url from image tag containing .gif link as src attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, redirect

I have my first URL as

```
https://www.obi.de/e27-led/philips-led-leuchtmittel-e27-gluehlampenform-7-w-3er-set-10-4-x-6-cm-h-x-/p/7620974
```

It contains image tag which can be located using xpath

```
//section[@id="Overview"]//div[@class="ads-previewslider__item ads-previewslider__item--video slick-slide slick-active"]//img
```

It plays video on the webpage when clicked. I have to extract video url from the webpage that is loaded in background after clicking the image tag using python.

I am not able to identify way how to extract this video URL.
Please help.

I tried requests module to get response from this[Link](https://www.obi.de/e27-led/philips-led-leuchtmittel-e27-gluehlampenform-7-w-3er-set-10-4-x-6-cm-h-x-/p/7620974)

but the response does not contain

```
https://mycliplister.com/lc/96807/?W3siU0VPIjpmYWxzZSwia2V5dHlwZSI6MTAwMDAsInJlcXVlc3RrZXkiOiI3NjIwOTc0IiwibGFuZyI6ImRlLCMjLGVuLGRlIn1d
```

which is the video url and I have to get this URL by following response after clicking the above mentioned image tag

Comment: Can't see your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.